# Is it possible to call Javascript method from c# winforms?

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms

I've a JavaScript file and it contains some methods. I want to call those methods from my winform application. Is it possible? If so can you give me a simple example?

I've tried like this

Process.Start("javascript:showuser('User1');return false;");

But it is not recogniging the showuser method. Because my js file is in remote location 
(ex : http://mysite.com/userprofile.js)

Can you help me to do this

Thank you

Comment: maybe this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167522/how-to-handle-javascript-events-via-webbrowser-control-for-winforms) can be useful

Answer (score 10):

You could use a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. Here's a sample [post](http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/).

```
webBrowser1.DocumentText = 
    @"<html><head>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      function testFunction() {
          alert('test');
      }
      </script>
      </head><body></body></html>";
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("testFunction");
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. But can you tell me where can I add js file in my application? or how can i refference to the js file (which is in remote location)

Comment: In my example I used inline script, but you can also reference your js using using the `src` attribute: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mysite.com/userprofile.js'></script>`

Comment: Hi.. I'm sorry it is not working for me. I dont know wats the wrong with me. Even that alert msg also not coming..

Comment: After setting the DocumentText, you have to handle the DocumentCompleted event, and do the InvokeScript call(s) in the handler.

Answer (score 8):

You could possibly use  a reference to Microsoft.JScript.dll, and something like the `Evaluator` method [from here](http://odetocode.com/Articles/80.aspx); but what exactly are you trying to do? If you are wanting to script your winform, I would be tempted to use [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). If you want to automate a **browser**, you might use the `WebBrowser` control.

Answer (score 2):

for being able to expose COM objects you must set:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
```

outside your class (within your namespace)

something like:

```
namespace webform
{
    [ComVisible(true)]

    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```