# How to handle Javascript events via WebBrowser control for WinForms

Tags: javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control, dom-events

I have read [WebBrowser Control from .Net — How to Inject Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153748/webbrowser-control-from-net-how-to-inject-javascript/154496#154496), [Is it possible to call Javascript method from C# winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988300/is-it-possible-to-call-javascript-method-from-c-winforms) and many others. Those examples were returns function value or alert window (synchronous calls). I have to get result from event handler (async call):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var o = new M.Build(document.getElementById("ZID"));

            M.Events.observe(o, o.Events.Success, function() {
                // I have to get some value!!
            });

            M.Events.observe(o, o.Events.Fault, function() {
                // I have to get some value!!
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Calling C# from JavaScript
>
> Simply put, you can expose a C# object
>   to the WebBrowser that the JavaScript
>   can call directly  The WebBrowser
>   class exposes a property called
>   ObjectForScripting that can be set by
>   your application and becomes the
>   window.external object within
>   JavaScript.  The object must have the
>   ComVisibleAttribute set true

C#:

```
 [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public class ScriptInterface
    {
        public void callMe()
        {
            … // Do something interesting
        }
    }

    webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptInterface();
```

Javascript:

```
window.external.callMe();
```

[Calling JavaScript in a WebBrowser control from C#](http://notions.okuda.ca/2009/06/11/calling-javascript-in-a-webbrowser-control-from-c/)

Comment: I assume the reason is because you can then inject js code to watch the event, and then have that js call back to your c# code.  That's what I'm about to try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is code I have. In the DocumentCompleted event ('cause I'm getting a page from online)

```
var wb = (WebBrowser)sender
//Lots of other stuff
object obj = wb.Document.InvokeScript("MyFunctionName");
```

Create a function that returns whatever value you need and invoke away.

You can also inject a script into the page

```
string js = "function MyFunctionName(){alert('Yea!');}";
HtmlElement el = wb.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element2 = (IHTMLScriptElement)el.DomElement;
element2.text = js;
head.AppendChild(el);
```

which can then be invoked. That's what I've done.

Comment: o.Events.Success will be fired asynchronously. it's not a solution.

Comment: I was thinking you could assign the value you need to a variable and then have or inject a function that returns that value.

Comment: The question is: when should I invoke this function. I don't know the time when the event would be executed. :(

Comment: If the function that returned the value that you invoke returns some form of an identifier when the value hasn't been set, then you'll know it hasn't been run yet. Without some type of indicator, you can't know if the function has run yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your webBrowser control is in a form, you can do the following:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class Form1
{

    public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = this;
    }

    public void CallMe()
    {
        //.... this method can be called in javascript via window.external.CallMe();
    }
}
```