# Detecting if ActiveX content has loaded?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, loading

I have a WebBrowser component that loads a webpage containing ActiveX content, the content has a loading screen which is a simple bar and a black background, when the content is loaded the background vanishes and another colour is seen, I'll set the component's dimensions so that the ActiveX content fits in perfectly. How do I detect if the content has loaded??

Answer (score 0):

When the activex is loaded, the object element will raise the [onreadystatechange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536957(v=vs.85).aspx) event. The state codes are documented in [Communicating Control Readiness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768179(v=vs.85).aspx).

See [How to handle javascript events via WebBrowser control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167522/how-to-handle-javascript-events-via-webbrowser-control-for-winforms) for handling html element events.